# Redirect any DomainName.com/FolderName to DomainName.com using .htaccess

Tags: linux, .htaccess

I want redirect any RandomDomainName.com/FolderName to RandomDomainName.com using .htaccess.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1):

put this in root .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^FolderName/?.*$ http://randomdomain.com [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Can randomdomain.com be a keyword?

Comment: What do you mean by keyword here? you mean to say http://randomdomain.com/FolderName/xyz. Here xyz as keyword?

Comment: Can i write

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/

Comment: The above URL works, if any user hits www.say-your-domain.com/FolderName/anything-string here, would always redirect to the defined URL in .htaccess i.e. here "http://randomdomain.com". Between, I'm sorry I did not get what keyword meant here.

Comment: also have a look at the site of how easy to implement .htaccess rules http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-tips-and-tricks.html

Comment: If someone types in xyz.com/abc so can I use %{REQUEST_URI} to route it back to xyz.com.  xyz.com is an assumption, it can be 123.net, nmo.org.

Comment: xyz.com would be %{HTTP_HOST} while  %{REQUEST_URI} would be xyz.com/abc, in that case your rewrite condition would be %{REQUEST_URI} %{HTTP_HOST}